# Cannot launch SQL Shell from PostgreSQL Installation on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, installation, windows-10

I have recently installed PostgreSQL to my Windows 10 following [this](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/install-postgresql/) tutorial. When I completed the installation, I failed to launch the SQL shell -- I could only see the pgAdmin interface in my installation. I uninstalled and installed PostgreSQL a few times, and the result was always the same. Would anyone be able to help with figuring out how can I get access to the SQL shell?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you start `cmd.exe` and then enter `psql`?

Comment: Doing 'psql --version' from the command prompt works fine, it's just the shell that comes with the installation that did not work, I guess.

Comment: "psql" is the shell for PostgreSQL. Try using this with replacing all the require input:    psql "postgres://username:password@hostname:5432/database_name"

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "failed to launch the SQL shell" then? `psql` **is** the "SQL shell"

Comment: I think that there needs to be a separate program called "sql shell" that comes with the installation, in addition to being able to use the "psql" command from cmd? Is that not the case?